# How to align data cell elements in a row in html table?

Tags: html, css, html-table, inline-styles

I have a screenshot as shown below which I have to replicate in HTML/CSS.

[image]

At this moment, I am able to replicate this in [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1nob7tyg/3/embedded/result) **with the two row elements** (at the bottom of the fiddle) **not  properly aligned inside the border**.

**Problem Statement:**

I wondering what changes I have to do in the **inline style** so that the **2 row elements** get properly inside the border.

The snippets of HTML and inline style codes which I have used in order to get that are:

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" width="100%" style="font-size:20px;border-top: 4px solid #484848;border-bottom: 4px solid #484848;">
        <tr>
          <td style="padding-left:5%;width:70%;">poster - HST 13%</td>
          <td style="padding-bottom:1%;">1</td>
          <td style="padding-bottom:1%;">$20</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td style="padding-left:5%;width:70%;">deposit not included in the location</td>
          <td style="padding-bottom:1%;">1</td>
          <td style="padding-bottom:1%;">$20</td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Remove the padding-left to start with.

Comment: @Paulie_D From where do you want to use padding-left ?

Comment: https://codepen.io/Paulie-D/pen/qKYBMX?editors=1000#0

Comment: @Paulie_D Thanks for the answer. I am wondering if you can update it in the fiddle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To fix this, add a `width: 12%` to the 2nd `<td>`

```
<td style="padding-bottom:1%;  width: 12%;">1</td>
```

Hope this helps :)

```html
<html>
<body>


<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" width="100%" class="mobile" style="margin: 0 auto;" align="center">


<tr>
      <td>
        <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" width="100%" style="font-size:20px;border-top: 2px solid #484848;padding-top: 2%;
    padding-bottom: 2%;">
          <tr >
            <td style="padding-left:8%;width:70%;padding-bottom:1%;">item</td>
            <td style="padding-bottom:1%;">qty</td>
   <td style="padding-bottom:1%;">price</td>
          </tr>  
     <tr>
            <td style="padding-left:5%;width:70%;padding-bottom:1%;">This is great tool</td>
            <td style="padding-bottom:1%;">2</td>
   <td style="padding-bottom:1%;">$120</td>
          </tr>   
    <tr>
            <td style="padding-left:5%;width:70%;padding-bottom:1%;">deliver to my location</td>
            <td style="padding-bottom:1%;">1</td>
   <td style="padding-bottom:1%;">$20</td>
          </tr>  
    <tr>
            <td style="padding-left:5%;width:70%;padding-bottom:1%;">pick up from my location</td>
            <td style="padding-bottom:1%;">1</td>
   <td style="padding-bottom:1%;">$20</td>
          </tr> 
    </table>
</td>
</tr> 



  <tr>
      <td>
        <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" width="100%" style="font-size:20px;border-top: 4px solid #484848;border-bottom: 4px solid #484848;">
      
       
    <tr>
            <td style="padding-left:5%;width:70%;">poster - HST 13%</td>
            <td style="padding-bottom:1%;">1</td>
   <td style="padding-bottom:1%;">$20</td>
          </tr>  
    <tr>
            <td style="padding-left:5%;width:70%;">deposit not included in the location</td>
            <td style="padding-bottom:1%;  width: 12%;">1</td>
   <td style="padding-bottom:1%;">$20</td>
          </tr> 
    </table>
</td>
</tr> 

</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Although, it worked but I have one quick question. Why adding width:12% fix this issue ? I am just following flow. Why in the last 2 elements of row, the elements get shift towards the left ?

Comment: Because you have 2 different tables with different content size in each cell. Try the next [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1nob7tyg/8/) You can see I change the headers and the content of the cells. No need for css adjustment.